# Ag-grid-enterprise causing issues with header titles disappearing

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I installed ag-grid-enterprise with no issues. After adding the import statement "import ag-grid-enterprise" so I could use the package, the header titles on my ag-grid table disappeared. This is a basic ag-grid table. Does anyone have any ideas on what I should try? I have already contacted ag grid support.

Update: It turns out it was some custom CSS causing the issue. Never mind.

Comment: There's not really enough information here for this to be answerable. Here's an example which might help: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular-example/tree/master/webpack2. Or maybe this one: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-more-details/#example-rich-grid-using-markup.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: Never mind. It turns out it was some custom CSS causing the issue.